# What is the Pythonic way to iterate over set intersection and exclusions?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, iteration, set-intersection

`set_of_A_key` and `set_of_B_key`are two set of keys of dictionary `dict_A` and `dict_B`. I want operate over the dictionary values for the keys in the following three sets:

`(set_of_A_key & set_of_B_key)`,
`(set_of_A_key - set_of_B_key)` and
`(set_of_B_key - set_of_A_key)`

What is the pythonic way to do this?

This one is elegant with very little code repetition, but does extra computation for find the key in set intersection and exclusions

```
only_A = (set_of_A_key - set_of_B_key)
only_B = (set_of_B_key - set_of_A_key)

for key in (set_of_A_key | set_of_B_key):
    if key in only_A:
        A_val = dict_A[key]
        B_val = 0
    elif key in only_B:
        B_val = dict_B[key]
        A_val = 0
    else:
        B_val = dict_B[key]
        A_val = dict_A[key]
    some_function(A_val,B_val)
```

or this one faster but code repetition is present

```
for key in (set_of_A_key - set_of_B_key):
     some_function(dict_A[key],0) 
for key in (set_of_B_key - set_of_A_key):
     some_function(0,dict_B[key]) 
for key in (set_of_A_key & set_of_B_key):
     some_function(dict_A[key],dict_B[key])
```

or is there a better way to above?

Comment: you can use dict.viewkeys etc..

Comment: Are you actually looking for the symmetric_difference?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
I'm not looking for symmetric_difference, but the `dict.viewkeys` lead helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it way too complicated for yourself. You appear to be creating *default values for missing keys*, so the following is far simpler:

```
for key in dict_A.viewkeys() | dict_A.viewkeys():
    some_function(dict_A.get(key, 0), dict_B.get(key, 0))
```

using the `dict.get()` function to substitute a default for a missing key.

Note that I used the [`dict.viewkey()` dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) to provide the set here. If you are using Python 3, then `dict.keys()` is a dictionary view already; [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) act as sets.

Comment: Thanks!
Using above, the code became faster elegant and short :)